# How much damage does it take to destroy metal foundation steps?

Tags: rust

I want to know how much damage it takes to destroy metal foundation steps for metal pick, beancan and satchel.

Answer (score 1):

Though calculated for walls, they do take the same damage . the [health for metal](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Building#Sheet_Metal_Tier) (i presume you meant sheet metal) is 750 health

[Satchel](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Satchel_Charge) takes 13 satchel to destroy 750/13 = just under 58 (57,6)

[beancan](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Beancan_Grenade) takes 63 beancan to destroy 750/63 = just under 12 (11,9)

[pickaxe](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Pick_Axe) 1500/20 is 75 pickaxes does 0,5 damage 750/0,5 = 1500 swings

(can't find the durability loss per hit so no accurate number) but should be roughly 1500 swing (lets say durability starts at 100 according to wiki it can be anything from 1/5 durability loss per swing. since you are hitting metal. so if 5 means 20 hits per pickaxe.